# Difference between Salesforce Connect and Heroku Connect

Tags: integration, heroku, largedatavolumes, heroku-connect, salesforce-connect

Can someone explain the difference between Salesforce Connect and Heroku Connect.

In the below image why they have to use both Salesforce connect and Heroku Connect. Cant they just use Heroku connect to achieve what they intended to achieve?

[image]

(Source:https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/connectors-for-data-integration/archive-and-consolidate-salesforce-data)

Comment: In this specific diagram, Heroku Connect could have been used on the left side as well. They're showing you Connect to illustrate the spectrum of possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference between Heroku Connect and Salesforce Connect is Heroku Connect synchronizes records between a Heroku Database and Salesforce (a copy of the data is kept on both systems). Salesforce Connect doesn't keep any of the data locally (good for your data limit). Unless you need Salesforce Connect for the previous data saving or data residency requirements Heroku Connect is just as suitable. Although I think in this case it's just an example don't overthink it :D

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 orgs.

- 1 main org
- 2 sales orgs
- 1 service org.

They want to **centralize data** that is created on boths **sales** and **service** orgs.
In order to do that, they need to use **Heroku Connect** as the data is created in the sf orgs and **replicated on a postgress** database.

In the **main org**, they want to access this data only to **view it**, or make a report. So, **Salesforce Connects** lets you access the postgress database without having to replicate the data in the main org using a **external object**.